# How to do request HTTP Digest auth with Node.JS?

Tags: node.js, httprequest, digest, digest-authentication, http-digest

I have to write some code with Node.JS for an API documentation, but I tried the last few days all the solutions I could found on the web (including Stack of course) without succes...

My API use HTTP Digest Auth and that's the problem, I was able to connect, that's was not a big deal but everytime I got the same return :

```
Got response : 401
HTTP Digest Authentication required for "api.example.com"
```

You can show my base code below without auth! Because I don't know what I can do after all the try I did :

```
var http = require('http')

var options = {
    host: 'api.example.com',
    path: '/example/1.xml',
};

var request = http.get(options, function(res){
    var body = "";
    res.on('data', function(data){
        body += data;
    })
    res.on('end', function(){
        console.log('Got response : ' + res.statusCode);
        console.log(body);
    })
    res.on('error', function(e){
        console.log('Got error : ' +e.message);
    });
});
```

One of my last try was to use this module https://npmjs.org/package/request but he doesn't work too as everytime I got 401 !

For more information I was able to connect and GET the information I needed from my API with Ruby, Python, php, and Java so I'm sure my API is working well and the information I pass are correct.
I use the last stable of Node v0.10.11 !

If someone can help me or have a solution up to date i will be glad.

EDIT : 
I will add some details about my test with the module [Mickael/request](https://npmjs.org/package/request)

First Try :

```
var request = require('request')

var options = {
    'url': 'http://api.example.fr/example/1.xml',
    'auth': {
        'user': 'test',
        'pass': 'test',
        'sendImmediately': false
    }
};

var request = request.get(options, function(error, response, body){
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){
        console.log('body : ' + body)
    }
    else{
        console.log('Code : ' + response.statusCode)
        console.log('error : ' + error)
        console.log('body : ' + body)
    }
});
```

Second Try :

```
var request = require('request')

request.get('http://api.example.fr/example/1.xml', function(error, response, body){
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){
        console.log('body : ' + body)
    }
    else{
        console.log('Code : ' + response.statusCode)
        console.log('error : ' + error)
        console.log('body : ' + body)
    }
}).auth('test', 'test', false);
```

but the return is still the same 401

Answer (score 15):

Here's your example corrected to use `request` as per it's API.

```
var options = {
  uri: 'http://api.example.fr/example/1.xml',
  auth: {
    user: 'test',
    pass: 'test',
    sendImmediately: false
  }
};
request(options, function(error, response, body){
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){
        console.log('body : ' + body)
    }
    else{
        console.log('Code : ' + response.statusCode)
        console.log('error : ' + error)
        console.log('body : ' + body)
    }
});
```

The request chainable style API is a bit confusing (IMHO), but I believe you can make it work that way as well.

Comment: Thank you for the suggest but as I said in my original post, I tried this solution you can find the link at the end of my post !

Comment: Post your code using `request`. "I tried it and it didn't work" isn't enough for us to actually help you.

Comment: I was editing for add my code using     request . thank you for your help :)

Comment: Hi sorry for late return but I tried and that's didn't work anymore :/ For more information my API is [Frapi]http://getfrapi.com/

Comment: Most irritating thing ever: saying "it didn't work". What was the status code? Programming is a DETAIL ORIENTED endeavor. I can't help you unless you start being detail-oriented. I ran my example with 'http://getfrapi.com/example/1.xml' and got a 404. Can you get your request to work using `curl` on the command line? `curl -v --digest --user test:test http://getfrapi.com/example/1.xml`, for example.

Comment: Hummm sorry I said it didn't work without details because it was the same status code 401 like everytime, so I'm sorry :)

Comment: Yes that's work with curl but I'm sorry you get 404 because the URL of my API is not the one I put on stack because I didn't have the authorization maybe by MP and if I create a test account you could try but I have to ask my boss before !

Comment: Hello I asked my boss for create a test account but that's not possible so he told me to stop with Node.JS for the moment. Thank you for your help !

Comment: Example by @PeterLyons worked for me. Digest auth works great.

Answer (score 1):

The digest auth in the request package seems to be incomplete.

You can try out: https://npmjs.org/package/http-digest-client ,its a pretty decent lightweight implementation for the digest authentication.

If you need to do a digest auth POST with a body message to be sent you can use request in conjunction with http-digest-client. After installing both just open up http-digest-client code under node-modules and replace its use of the http package with the request package api.

Answer (score 1):

**Try [urllib](https://www.npmjs.com/package/urllib) it will work with simple and disgest auth.**

```
const httpClient = require('urllib');
const url = 'https://site.domain.com/xmlapi/xmlapi';
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  rejectUnauthorized: false,
  // auth: "username:password" use it if you want simple auth
  digestAuth: "username:password",
  content: "Hello world. Data can be json or xml.",
  headers: {
     //'Content-Type': 'application/xml'  use it if payload is xml
     //'Content-Type': 'application/json' use it if payload is json 
    'Content-Type': 'application/text'
  }
};
const responseHandler = (err, data, res) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
  console.log(res.statusCode);
  console.log(res.headers);
  console.log(data.toString('utf8'));
}
httpClient.request(url, options, responseHandler);
```

Answer (score 0):

your sample is work

```
var request = require('request')

request.get('http://api.example.fr/example/1.xml', function(error, response, body){
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200){
        console.log('body : ' + body)
   }
    else{
       console.log('Code : ' + response.statusCode)
       console.log('error : ' + error)
       console.log('body : ' + body)
   }
}).auth('test', 'test', false);
```